# React Native TextInput Losing Focus After Every Character Entered on Keyboard

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Trying to figure out an issue with the TextInput component I have which is acting weird. Basically, after every keystroke, the textinput seems to be losing its focus.

Im implementing it as a search bar that is triggered / animated when a search icon is touched by the user:

```
                <TouchableHighlight 
                    activeOpacity={1}
                    underlayColor={"#ccd0d5"}
                    onPress={onFocus}
                    style={styles.search_icon_box}
                >
```

onFocus method:

```
const onFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);

    const input_box_translate_x_config = {
        duration: 200,
        toValue: 0,
        easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
    }

    const back_button_opacity_config = {
        duration: 200,
        toValue: 1,
        easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
    }

    // RUN ANIMATION
    timing(input_box_translate_x, input_box_translate_x_config).start();
    timing(back_button_opacity, back_button_opacity_config).start();

    ref_input.current.focus();
}
```

just a simple animation where when triggered the search bar will slide from the right side of the screen

```
                <Animated.View
                    style={[ styles.input_box, {transform: [{translateX: input_box_translate_x}] } ]}
                >
                    <Animated.View style={{opacity: back_button_opacity}}>
                        <TouchableHighlight
                            activeOpacity={1}
                            underlayColor={"#ccd0d5"}
                            onPress={onBlur}
                            style={styles.back_icon_box}
                        >
                            <MaterialIcons name="arrow-back-ios" size={30} color="white" />
                        </TouchableHighlight>
                    </Animated.View>
                    <SearchBar 
                        placeholder='Search'
                        keyboardType='decimal-pad'
                        returnKeyType='done' 
                        ref={ref_input}
                        value={searchText}
                        onChangeText={search}
                        onClear={onBlur}
                        onSubmitEditing={onBlur}
                        onFocus={() =>console.log("focus received" ) }
                        onBlur={() => console.log("focus lost") }
                    />
                </Animated.View>
```

Search

```
const search = (searchText) => {
    setSearchText(searchText);

    let filteredData = AnimalList.filter(function (item) {
        return item.tag_number.toString().includes(searchText);
    });

    setFilteredData(filteredData);
}
```

So, when I clicked on the search icon, the search bar will present itself through animated view and the keyboard will automatically be focused. However, after entering a single character on the keyboard the searchbar just vanishes with keyboard still showing.

I tried to debug using `onFocus={() =>console.log("focus received" ) }` and it looks like the searchBar is still focused on, its just not showing

**EDIT: Issue Video Here https://github.com/renwid/test/issues/1**

Comment: What does your `search` fn look like?

Comment: Added search fn in post

Comment: I would suspect that that's because you're setting the state in your fn, making the whole component rerender and thus applying the initial styles, without the animation. Can you try to confirm that?

Comment: seems like thats the case, the re-renders itself after every keystroke, really confused about this issue